# Microsoft Office application registration keys reported as incorrect

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

My acer netbook has some problems with Microsoft programs, such as Word and Powerpoint. It requests that I enter a registration key, which is located on the underside of the computer, and then when the code has been entered, I am informed that the key is incorrect.

I would like to know if there is any way to make the netbook accept my registration key (for I have checked numerous times, and it is the correct one.) I do not wish to lose the Microsoft programs, because they are useful for school. Would anyone mind to help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Office keys are not located on the bottom of the laptop. That's the Windows license.

Office 2010 often (but not always) comes pre-loaded but *unlicensed* on new machines.

If you are in fact licensed to use Office, you should have received a proper key located on a card, when you purchased the laptop.

If you did not receive a license, you must purchase one. Educational licenses are not expensive.

Comment: I would say "often" comes, not always. Also make sure you qualify for an educational license.

Comment: There was a time, within the past 10 years, when MS-Office software included a Product Key sticker that the user was supposed to stick on to their computers.  I remember installing these for a few clients, and placing them right next to the Windows XP Product Key sticker (so it would be easy to find).  For some reason Microsoft stopped shipping these stickers (I assume because most people weren't sticking them on their computers).

Comment: Edited per @KCotreau's suggestion.